Is a front/back architecture really necessary for a complete app?
I got a quick question around technical architecture of an application.
I need to create a non static webapp with a database. Usually I'd do a front + back app, I have started a Vite + Vue front and a Java + postgres back.
Since I do not plan/need to allow several front to conect to the back I was asking myself if i could simply delete the back, and add a Library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres for exemple) to the front to plug directly to the database (it's a personnal project, not a multiple team stuff).
It will allow me to manage just one package delivery which seems simpler, and not maintain a back which is praticly just an input/ouput converter to the database.
Does this type of architecture have a name to do some research of my own after ?

I believe that what you are referring to is a "static webpage" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page.
Keep in mind that without a back-end, it would not be possible for you to store the user's data outside of the app. This would mean that all data your app can access will be local since your postgress is stored client side.
